# How can i override my custom styles to useragent stylesheet in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm facing problem while i'm giving any styles to input checkbox there is not getting any changes because of user agent styles. and i have tried it using custom class also still not getting any styles.. if having any solution then please share..

Comment: This has been asked before check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really style checkboxes directly, most CSS3 workarounds involve using pseudo selectors on labels.

I'd recommend looking into checkbox specific styling, try the following resources:

http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953